# Null Reference Exception in line checking for Null?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have a fairly simple piece of code:

```
Private _PurchaseDelivery as PurchaseDelivery

Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As PurchaseDeliveryItem)
    Dim SKUBin As SKUBin
    If _PurchaseDelivery IsNot Nothing AndAlso _PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.HasValue Then
        SKUBin = item.StockOrderUnit.SKU.SKUBins.GetByBinID(_PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.Value)
        item.SKUBin = SKUBin
    End If

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

Which is inside a class which overrides a custom list base. The code is occassionaly throwing an unhandled exception, `System.NullReferenceException`, on this line when used in production:

```
    If _PurchaseDelivery IsNot Nothing AndAlso _PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.HasValue Then
```

DeafultSKUBinID is declared as an `Integer?` (Nullable Int) in the `PurchaseDelivery` class. I cannot see what might be causing this error, why would this be returning an error?

Comment: Can't reproduce with a debugger attached? Perhaps it is a slightly different build? Line-number mismatch?

Comment: Thanks. Same build (exact same build) and unable to reproduce with debugger attached or on any Dev machine. Recompiled (to make sure it wasn't some quirk) and still occurring. Is very infrequent, but really odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to my own problem. The class causing the error was returning the wrong line number in the exception. I have no idea why.

Any exception in this file returns a line number that it 1 less that the code the caused the exception, so the null reference is on the next line. I have no idea why this occurs, I have removed all whitespace in the file and recompiled and will see if that causes the issue to go away.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

As per code (In OP) snippet `PurchaseDelivery` in not instantiated (may be it was created somewhere). You may try to change the if statement like:

```
Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As PurchaseDeliveryItem)
    Dim SKUBin As SKUBin
    If IsNothing(_PurchaseDelivery) Then
           Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsNothing(_PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID) Then
           Exit Sub
    End If
    If _PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.HasValue Then
        SKUBin = item.StockOrderUnit.SKU.SKUBins.GetByBinID(_PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.Value)
        item.SKUBin = SKUBin
    End If
    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

Comment: The `AndAlso` posed in the question achieves the same thing.

Comment: @DennisPalmer - OP has tried that case (problem) and you see he/she posted here. There are number of cases where exceptions can be raised. Might be DefaultSKUBinID is null.

Comment: Removed my downvote after answer edited although exiting the method prevents `MyBase.InsertItem` from being called, which I don't believe is the OP's desired outcome.

Comment: @DennisPalmer - Well! right now we all are guessing about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

_PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID is nothing.

```
Private _PurchaseDelivery as PurchaseDelivery

Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As PurchaseDeliveryItem)
    Dim SKUBin As SKUBin
    If _PurchaseDelivery IsNot Nothing AndAlso _PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID isnot nothing andalso _PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.HasValue Then
        SKUBin = item.StockOrderUnit.SKU.SKUBins.GetByBinID(_PurchaseDelivery.DefaultSKUBinID.Value)
        item.SKUBin = SKUBin
    End If

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought the purpose of nullable types was to allow them to be set to nothing, and then be able to test them for null by checking .HasValue

Comment: Just to test, I created the following console app:
'
    Sub Main()
        Dim i As Integer?
        i = 1
        Console.WriteLine("HasValue is: " & i.HasValue)
        Console.WriteLine("Value is: " & i)
        i = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine("HasValue is: " & i.HasValue)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
'
Which outputs the following, as expected:
HasValue is: True
Value is: 1
HasValue is: False

If the system was crashing because the above is true, the last Console.write line would give the same UE?

Comment: My answer was based on the fact that nothing else on that line could be causing that exception; though I am not sure how that error is occurring. Can you post the definition for PurchaseDelivery?